# Cannot find item in list based on index in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

im using a sorted list in netlogos but when i run my code i get an error message that it can't find element 3 because the lenght of the list is 3, that sounds really strange and counter intuative to me. what goes wrong

```
 globals [
    allehøjder
    min_højde
    nedre_højde
    median_højde
    øvre_højde
    max_højde
    ]

breed [personer en_person]

personer-own [højde skostørrelse]


to setup   ; runs when the button "setup" is pressed
  clear-all
  ;kom alle højder ind i højde
  ;sorter højde listen
  ;find 5 kvartil værdien ud fra højder[]

    create-personer 3
    [

      set color white
      set højde (150  + ( random ( 190 - 150 )))
      set skostørrelse (38 + (random ( 47 -  38 )) )
      setxy random-xcor random-ycor
      set size 10
     
    ]
  

  set allehøjder [højde] of personer
  set alleskostørrelser [skostørrelse] of personer
  show sort allehøjder
  show sort alleskostørrelser
;sætter de 5 kvartilværdier for højde
  ; sætter min
  set min_højde item 1 (sort allehøjder)
  ;sætter max
 **bold** set max_højde item 3 (sort allehøjder)
  ; sætter median
  ifelse 3 mod 2 = 0
  ;lige antal
  [
    set median_højde item ((3 + 1 / 2) ) (sort allehøjder)
     ]
  ;ulige antal
  [
     set median_højde ((item ((3 + 1) / 2) (sort allehøjder) + item (((3 + 1) / 2) + 1) (sort allehøjder)) / 2)
  ]
 
 
   reset-ticks
end
```

regards morten

Answer (score 2):

The indexing of lists' [items](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#item) starts from 0, hence the third element will have index 2.

The [NetLogo Programming Guide](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/) and the NetLogo Dictionary linked above should have you covered with this type of problems.